# how to store a date/time object to DB

Tags: jdbc

i'm new to java. now i have a question: how to store a date/time object to Oracle database?

for example, I want DB to track every reminder which consists of an ID, date/time and a message. Should i do any type conversion?

please give me an example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store a timestamp into a number field.